# Наполнить массив, многомерными объектами

Tags: c#, ado.net

У меня есть такая часть кода: получаю с базы данных строки, с первого столбца необходимо получить значения Start, со второго End и обьединить в обьект, переходя к следующей строке тоже самое.
Не понимаю, как выполнить цикл, чтобы наполнить массив.

```
public static Productions[] GetProductions () {


            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=PressShop.accdb";

            using ( var connection = new OleDbConnection (ConnectionString) ) {

                connection.Open ();

                using ( var sqlComommand = new OleDbCommand ("select * FROM ref_summary", connection) ) {

                    sqlComommand.ExecuteNonQuery ();

                    var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter (sqlComommand);
                    var dataSet = new DataSet ();
                    dataAdapter.Fill (dataSet, "ref_summary");

                    var i = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;



                    var results = new Productions[i];

                foreach ( DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows ) {

                    results.Append (new Productions () { Start = dr[1].ToString (), End = dr[2].ToString () });
                }

                Console.WriteLine (results.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```

Необходимо наполнить массив из цикла и на выходе получить это.
В примере только 3 обьекта, но их там может быть 10к и выше.

```
    var result = new Productions[]
    {
        new Productions () { Start = "...", End = "..." },
        new Productions () { Start = "...", End = "..." },
        new Productions () { Start = "...", End = "..." }
        ...
    };
    
Console.WriteLine (result);
//Press_Shop_NMGR.Data.Productions[]
    return result;
```

Comment: `new Productions[]` -> `new List<Productions>()`. Заполнение `new Productions () { Start = "...", End = "..."}, ` -> `result.Add(new Productions () { Start = "...", End = "..."});`. Если надо массив, то в конце `return result.ToArray();`. Ну, либо берите из базы то, сколько сейчас там строк, инициализируйте новый массив с указанным числом, а дальше циклом `result[i] = new Productions(){ ... };`. Если вопрос не про это, то я значит вообще не понял в чем у вас трудности...

Comment: `sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery ();` - это зачем?

Comment: Зачем DataSet? Достаточно DataTable.

Comment: DataAdapter сам может создать, открыть и закрыть соединение. Не нужно ему "помогать".

Comment: И зачем метка `wpf`? Вопрос хоть как-то относится к этому GUI-фреймворку?

Comment: к wpf относится но это отдельный разговор.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы можете в виде кода показать реализацию? я только начал изучать C# и для меня пока всё это как вилами по воде)) по ходу дела на практике начинаю понимать.

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин А я в виде чего показал? Прям даже сказал что и на что заменить.

Comment: Текущий вопрос никак не связан с WPF. Поэтому не нужно ставить эту метку. То, что код используется в проекте WPF, ничего не значит.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
ты здесь для чего? Вопросы только задавать?  Я пытаюсь разобраться в новом для себя а ты тут как диванный советчик.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня просто ругается на эту часть кода new Productions[] -> new List<Productions>();

Comment: Я надеюсь вы не пишете `new Productions[] -> new List<Productions>();`, а пишете `new List<Productions>();`?

Comment: я сделал потом вот так, List<Productions> result = new List<Productions> (); Но в конечном итоге я не получаю того чего хотел)

Comment: как мне потом этой переменной var result = new Productions[] { } сказать что внутри тебя всё то что я делал в цикле, сейчас код поправлю и опубликую что я делаю

Comment: Код поправил,  вместо result (статических данных), мне нужно вернуть results, но в том же виде что и result.

Comment: понимаю что я скорей всего объявляю не правильно

Comment: Я вам очень сильно советую понимать то, что вы делаете, а также следовать подсказкам студии. Вот допустим, написали `results.ToArray();`, ок, только этот метод возвращает вам массив, вы его занесли куда-либо? Нет. Так может `return results.ToArray();`? А еще лучше избавиться от этой конвертации из коллекции в массив, возвращайте сразу методов массив (`List<...>`). Далее, `Console.WriteLine(results);` - зачем..? Что вы ожидаете от этого? Вывод всех значений на экран? Ну, так не выйдет, ибо по умолчанию, конвертация к `string` у почти любого объекта в C# отдает тип, а не "внутренности".

Comment: я тем самым сопоставлял как раз типы) у меня вроде как типы сошлись, он у статического и динамического объектов так же выдает длину. снова поправил код

Answer (score 0):

Тут пишут, мол "зачем датасет", и что "достаточно дататейбл".

Так вот, дело в том, что для таких задачь вообще лучше использовать датаридер. И не только для таких. Забудьте про датасеты и дататаблы - это уже устаревшая, "тяжелая" модель работы с данными. Используйте датаридеры, а для моделей данных лучше вообще использовать ORM вроде Entity Framework.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо, начну гуглить

Comment: Будет здорово, если покажете пример кода, с использованием датаридера. / В данный момент ваше сообщение не является ответом.